# Instant notification by push pull method in PHP

Tags: php, push-notification, pull-request, instant-messaging

I want to get instant notification like facebook and other live chats, when one user or admin will update anything. But, I can do it without using jquery timer ajax.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you want to use websockets http://socketo.me/

Comment: I am using pusher.com (free for limited usage)

Comment: I can do it with setInterval function of javascript. But, I think this is not good practice. I think there are some other dynamic process or technology. 
But, I don't know them.

Answer (score 0):

**Web sockets** is your answer. Refer http://socketo.me/

You can also use **[node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)** to achieve the same.